# Polling Google sites for changes

Tags: node.js, api, google-api, google-sites

I need an event that is being fired whenever something changes on my google sites site.

There is an XML feed with all the latest changes. I am planning on polling this feed with Zapier and when something changes Zapier will make a http request to a url that I provide so I get my event.

This works fine as long as the site is public, but in my case it is not.

So I think about building a proxy for the feed that google provides. The proxy will call the feed with the proper authentication and pass the contents. Zapier will call the proxy with a Zapier friendly authentication mechanism.

I figured that I need to call the google feed with a service account. So how do I do that with node.js?

I have been looking here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ActivityFeed

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I have made a proxy with basic authentication that is accessed via https. This proxy will pass through the activity feed of the Google site that I am interested in.

I built the proxy in node.js with the googleapis module. Here is a piece of the code I use:

```
var jwtClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
    client_id_email,
    __dirname + 'key.pem',
    null, ['https://sites.google.com/feeds/'],
    'user@domain.org'
);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, token) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    return rest({
        path: 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/{domainName}/{siteName}',
        headers: {
            "GData-Version": "1.4",
            Authorization: token.token_type + ' ' + token.access_token
        },
        params: {
            domainName: 'domain.org',
            siteName: 'site',
        },
    }).done(function(result) {
        res.set(result.headers);
        res.send(result.entity);
    }, next);
});
```

The username (user@domain.org) in the example is a user that the service account impersonates. This user must have acces to the site.

I put the service account key in a file name 'key.pem' in this example.

Now you must allow accesd to the service account for the domain you want to access. You do this on the admin site of the domain (admin.google.com).

1. Go to security
2. Go to advanced settings
3. Go to API client access
4. There you have to add the client_id of the service client

And now... it works :-) !!! \o/